# Lorentz Transformation Time Dilation Equation

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, time-dilation

I occasionally see slightly different equations being used to calculate time measured by a moving observer.

Sometimes this equation is used:
$$t'=\frac {1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\left(t-\frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$

Other times, this simpler version is used:

$$t'=\frac {1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\left(t\right)$$

Why can the second term (Eq 1) be omitted in some cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is the Lorentz transformation between two inertial frames.

Let's consider an event observed in an inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$ without a prime, denoted as $(t, x)$. For convenience, we won't consider the $y$ and $z$ axes. An inertial frame $\mathcal{O}'$ moving with a velocity $+v$ along the $x$-axis with respect to this frame $\mathcal{O}$ observes the same event as $(t', x')$, and it is given by:
$$
t' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right),\tag{1}
$$
$$
x' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left(x - vt\right).\tag{2}
$$

The second one is the formula for the interval between two events.
Two events happening at the same location in the inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$ with coordinates $(t_1, x)$ and $(t_2, x)$ are observed in the inertial frame $\mathcal{O}'$ with coordinates $(t_1', x_1')$ and $(t_2', x_2')$, respectively, where:
$$
t_1' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left(t_1 - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right),\tag{3}
$$
$$
t_2' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left(t_2 - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right).\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, if the time interval between the two events in frame $\mathcal{O}$ is $t_2 - t_1$, the time interval between the same events in frame $\mathcal{O}'$ can be expressed as:
$$
t_2' - t_1' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\left(t_2 - t_1\right) \tag{5}
$$
If we denote $t_2 - t_1$ and $t_2' - t_1'$ as time intervals represented by the symbols $\Delta t$ and $\Delta t'$, respectively, the second equation is equivalent to:
$$
\Delta t' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} \Delta t \tag{6}
$$

Comment: Does the first set of equations only apply in a situation where x’ = x at t’ = t = 0? Is there a method apply similar transformations when two objects don’t share a common spatial location at some time?

Comment: Eq. (1), (2) can always be applied under the conditions described above. Eq. (3), (4) assume that the two events have the same $x$ coordinate in the inertial frame $\mathcal{O}$. If that is not the case, the term $-vx/c^2$ cannot be simplified, but the equations can still be written as $t_2' - t_1' = \gamma (t_2 - t_1 - v/c^2 (x_2 - x_1))$, where $\gamma$ is Lorentz factor.